# Angular remove values from Laravel form

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I have a angular module named `shop` and controller named `CartCtrl`:

```
angular.module('shop').controller('CartCtrl',  function($scope, $http, ngCart) {

    $scope.order_name = null;

    $scope.order_phone = null;
});
```

In template i have:

```
   <div class="modal-body" ng-module="shop" ng-controller="CartCtrl">
      {!! Form::model(Auth::user()->profile, [ 'route' => 'order.send'], [ 'id'=>'order_form']) !!}
   <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::text('name', old('name'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ваше имя', 'ng-model'=>'order_name']) !!}

   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::text('phone', old('phone'), ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ваш телефон', 'ng-model'=>'order_phone']) !!}
   </div>
      {!! Form::close() !!}

  </div>
```

But when I go to the page and look at the form, then it is empty. But if I take away: `ng-module="shop" ng-controller="CartCtrl"` all will be ok. Why is that?

**UPD:**

If i remove `ng-model` it will be the same, values in inputs has will be empty

Comment: Because you initialised the values to null here `order_name = null` and here `order_phone = null` what do you expect ??

Comment: @Maraboc And I was there to put it?

Comment: What ? i said what do you expect in the form in the first time ??

Comment: I am expect `Auth::user()->profile->name` and `Auth::user()->profile->phone` values

Comment: Is there eny method for submit your form in the `CartCtrl`?